# Ansible - Set variable based on condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a role called `kernel`. In its vars file `kernel/vars/main.yml`, is it possible to set the values of variables based on a condition?

For example, say I have a playbook like this that calls my kernel role:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - role: kernel
      vars:
        version: '4.3'
```

is it possible to do something like this in `kernel/vars/main.yml`?:

```
---
if 'version' == '4.3':
  kernel_dir:  "/mnt/public/kernel/4.3"
  kernel_headers: "linux-headers-4.3.deb"
  kernel_image: "linux-image-4.3.deb"
  kernel_libc: "linux-libc-dev_4.3.deb"
  kernel_version: "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.3"
if 'version' == '4.2':
  kernel_dir: "/mnt/public/kernel/4.2"
  kernel_headers: "linux-headers-4.2.deb"
  .. and so on
```

Also, is it possible to set a default value, so that if the role has been called with no value for `version`, it would get the vars for `4,3`?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the options into separate files, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat roles/kernel/vars/4.2.yml 
kernel_dir:  /mnt/public/kernel/4.2
kernel_headers: linux-headers-4.2.deb

shell> cat roles/kernel/vars/4.3.yml 
kernel_dir:  /mnt/public/kernel/4.3
kernel_headers: linux-headers-4.3.deb
```

Then [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task) the variables by *version*, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat roles/kernel/tasks/main.yml
- include_vars: "{{ version }}.yml"
- debug:
    var: kernel_dir
```

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - role: kernel
      vars:
        version: '4.3'
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [webservers] => 
  kernel_dir: /mnt/public/kernel/4.3
```

---

Notes

- The variables will be included at precedence 18. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)
- It's not necessary to include the path to *vars*. Quoting from [dir](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#parameter-dir)

> If the path is relative and the task is inside a role, it will look inside the role's vars/ subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

Since I had a similar requirement in the past I came to following approach

```yaml
- name: Initialize VERSION
  set_fact:
    VERSION: "4.3"
  when: VERSION == ''
```

since the variable is initialized for sure it is than possible to use

```yaml
kernel_dir: "/mnt/public/kernel/{{ VERSION }}"
kernel_headers: "linux-headers-{{ VERSION }}.deb"
kernel_image: "linux-image-{{ VERSION }}.deb"
kernel_libc: "linux-libc-dev_{{ VERSION }}.deb"
kernel_version: "Ubuntu, with Linux {{ VERSION }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that also works! Though I have other roles that need the import_role provided by the other comment. Will defiantly use that, thanks!!